# applying Python Isomap using sklearn.manifold how to get eigenvalues

Tags: python, scikit-learn, eigenvalue, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to use sklearn.manifold Isomap for dimensional reduction.
I have 10 column data and I used number of components = 4.

How can I get the weight of each component?
Is there a method to extract the eigenvalue of each component?

This is the code I used

```
from sklearn.manifold import Isomap

embedding = Isomap(n_components=4, n_neighbors=6)
X_transformed = embedding.fit_transform(X[:])
X_transformed.shape
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `kernel_pca` method and then you can find the eigenvalues:

```
embedding.kernel_pca_.eigenvalues_
```

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.manifold import Isomap
X, _ = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
X.shape
embedding = Isomap(n_components=2)
X_transformed = embedding.fit(X[:100])

print(embedding.kernel_pca_.eigenvalues_)
# [891862.11494232 201321.18711327]
```